# How to check if a node is near to another node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

for some time I have been trying to call a function when a node is near to another node. For this I first dealt with `SKPhysicBody`, but since the `didBegin()` function was never called, I wanted to ask if anyone has other idea, how you can check quite easily if a node is near to another node.

Struct:

```
struct physicBodyCharacters {

    static let cardNumber = 00000001 //1
    static let anotherCardNumber = 00000010 //2
    static let nobodyNumber = 00000100 //4
}
```

in viewDidLoad():

```
gameScene2.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.81)
    gameScene2.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

First Node:

```
card = SKSpriteNode(texture: cardTexture)
    card.position = CGPoint(x: gameScene2.size.width / 2 + 150, y: 95)
    card.zPosition = 3
    card.setScale(1)
    card.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: cardTexture, size: card.size)
    card.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    card.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.cardNumber)
    card.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.nobodyNumber)
    card.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.anotherCardNumber)
```

Second Node:

```
anotherCard = SKSpriteNode(texture: anotherCardTexture)
    anotherCard.position = CGPoint(x: 31 , y: 532)
    anotherCard.zPosition = 2
    anotherCard.setScale(1)
    anotherCard.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: anotherCardTexture, size: battlefieldCard0.size)
    anotherCard.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    anotherCard.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.anotherCardNumber)
    anotherCard.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.nobodyNumber)
    anotherCard.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.cardNumber)
```

didBegin() Function:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("contact")
    let contanctMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contanctMask
    {
    case UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.cardNumber) | UInt32(physicBodyCharacters.anotherCardNumber):
        print("hit")
    default:
        break
    } 
}
```

I would be very grateful for any answer.

Comment: It's difficult to debug why the `didMove()` method isn't being called without seeing your existing code.

Comment: @ZGski I have now added the code. However, this is not in the GameScene, but in another class.

Comment: By `didMove()` do you mean `didBegin()`? If  `didBegin()`is in another class, then you need to check carefully where your physicsworld contact delegate is set and where it points to.Any particular reason why you moved it to another class?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean of course `didBegin()`. I'm using this in another class because there is also a large amount of other code there that refers to the corresponding `ViewController`.